# How to fix React Hooks after upgrade to NextJS 9.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

After updating nextjs to 9.0.0 this problem occured during build.
 `nex^8.1.0  →   ^9.0.0`
In page components I am using the global store I set previously.

`const { state, dispatch } = React.useContext(React.createContext())`

The error message is
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined, > Build error occurred`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I have to provide a default value for `React.createContext()`
I had initial values, but I was passing them to `Store.Provider`,

```
export function StoreProvider(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const value = { state, dispatch };
  return <Store.Provider value={value}>{props.children}</Store.Provider>}
```

I simply had to add `initialState` to `createContext()`

```
export const Store = React.createContext({ state: initialState })
```